# Numerical Performance rating scale

Tags: performance-reviews, appraisal

What are the pros and cons of a numerical performance rating scale? I am building a performance management framework for my company - we're a startup and a small team of 25. I want to understand if numerical ratings would be the best way to go for us (vs descriptive rating scales). Are numerical ratings more demotivating or are they more understandable for employees than descriptive ones?

Answer (score 13):

It's always a mistake to try and apply numbers to something that's inherently descriptive.

In a team of 25, it's completely unnecessary. You are almost certain to create dysfunction.

Before attempting such folly, I strongly urge you to read "[Measuring and Managing Performance in Organizations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DY3KQX6)"

Comment: I strongly second reading the book. And remember Deming: "Just because you can't measure it doesn't mean you can't manage it" applies quite well to people.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't see much practical difference between single-digit numbers and the "greatly exceeds/exceeds/meets/falls short/falls badly short" bucket system, if there's a 1:1 napping between them. I presume both would be given on multiple axes, so the employee knows what they are and aren't doing well.

But in a small organization, you should be able to be more precise than that. "You did an outstanding job with X and Z, but I'm a bit disappointed with Y; let's work on that"l provides much better guidance for growth.

And in fact, some of the major companies which used the five-bucket classification system for the whole year -- IBM being one example -- have been replacing it with dynamically tracking individual tasks,l, updating both the list of tasks and the evaluations (in words as well as rankings!) throughout the year, marking them with how well they reflect each of N overall quality/innovation goals, and then summarizing for evaluation. This provides much more actionable feedback to the employees

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a performance management framework for my company -
> we're a startup and a small team of 25. I want to understand if
> numerical ratings would be the best way to go for us (vs descriptive
> rating scales).

I am assuming that the numerical scale is being used because the goals can be easily stated and measured; otherwise there is no difference between putting them into broad categories: below expectations, meets expectations, exceeds expectations.

A numerical scale is a great idea provided the following:

- Everybody knows the goals and the way points are earned before the year starts.
- The point system can't be manipulated.
- There also has to be a clearly defined comparison between different job titles. How do you compare a 1st year widget maker and a 10 year QA needs to be defined in advance.